# Where can one download or subscribe to end of day price data for Tokyo stocks?

Tags: stock-analysis, yahoo-finance, historical-data, online-data-source, japan

I am looking for free sites to download end-of-day stock data for Tokyo stocks but my efforts have been in vain. The best hope was Yahoo Finance but it does not provide end-of-day data for Tokyo stocks.I do not mind subscribing to a paid service as long as it is in the affordable range(around USD200 a year) for retail investors. Bloomberg and Thomson Reuters are too expensive for small guys like me.

Comment: I would still call them up and ask for a quote, if you aren't going to use them commercially. As they provide other services too, they could probably remove those services from the market data feed. But I would believe $200 would be too less to subscribe to market data.

Answer (score 1):

[Google Finance](https://www.google.com/finance?q=TYO%3A9201) certainly has data for Tokyo Stock Exchange (called `TYO` on Google) listings.  You could create a "portfolio" consisting of the stocks you care about and then visit it once per day (or write a script to do so).